# How to add neighborhood names from shp to csv data points QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

I'd like to add the neighborhoods listed in a shp file to the data points in a csv

Link to [shp](https://data.sfgov.org/Geographic-Locations-and-Boundaries/Neighborhood-Groups-Map/qc6m-r4ih)

Link to [csv](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Z91lphKSqVeVYPMHWuLRg-ZT3Dta-GjwJFwfwAH8#rows:id=1)

Here are the data points overlaid on the shapefile map of the neighborhoods.

[image]

I'd like to get these neighborhood names

[image]

Into this dataset, so that each data point has the correct neighborhood name

[image]

Adding what I've tried.

[image]

Clicked 'no'

[image]

Opened new shapefile, seems empty.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the tool "join attributes by location".have a look at my answer to this question: [Combine Shapefile with address information](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133529/combine-shapefile-with-address-information)

Just load the polygon layer into qgis and transform it to epsg 4326 (from 102643).

[image]

Then save the imported csv as shapefile and define the crs of the layer as EPSG4326.

[image]
[image]
deactivate otf-reprojection and do the join.
See the output:

[image]

Then you can save the layers as csv again:

[image]

Comment: In "join attributes by location" its output is a shapefile. I'm still confused on how I add the neighborhoods from the shapefile to the csv

Comment: Just save the shapefile as csv when you finished your spatial join(right click, save as...)

Comment: The shapefile seems empty. I added some pictures of the steps I took

Comment: Your crs have to match.On your first screenshot there seems to be a userdefined crs set for one of the layers.Apart from that you should save your imported csv as shapefile and use this file for the join

Comment: I loaded the data again and set both crs to "WGS 84 / UTM zone 10N". The two data sets are ending up in different locations. I'll add the links to the data sets above

Comment: The reason they end up in different locations is that they are in different coordinate systems. Try right clicking one of the layers, choosing Save As, and then save it in the same coordinate system as the other layer.

Comment: Just load the polygon layer into qgis and transform it to epsg 4326 (from 102643) .then define the csv layer as EPSG4326.deactivate otf-reprojection and do the join.Just tested it and works smoothly ;-)

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! The detailed answer really helped